# Django NoReverseMatch - Amadeus API

Tags: django, amadeus

I'm attempting to use an API as part of a project I'm working on and am having some difficulty currently:

**API**
https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/airport-and-city-search

**API - Python SDK**
https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-python

**Django API Guide**
https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/django-jquery-ajax-airport-search-autocomplete

I have followed the instructions from the above guide; however, I am receiving the following error when trying to render the index page which contains the code:

```
Reverse for 'origin_airport_search' not found. 'origin_airport_search' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

**Index Template:**

```
{% extends "flightfinder/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
<div id="mainhomepagediv">
    <div class="container-fluid px-0" id="mainhomepagediv">
        <div class="row mx-0">
            <div class="col-12 px-0">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/rHYzcyc/Landscape2.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 id="homepageh1">Where are you flying to?</h1>
        <div id="homepagebox">
            <div>
                <form id="homepageform" method="POST">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col">
                        <label id="homepageformlabel">From</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Origin city" id="inputOrigin">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col pb-3">
                        <label id="homepageformlabel">To</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Destination city">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                          <label id="homepageformlabel">Depart</label>
                          <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Origin city">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <label id="homepageformlabel">Return</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Destination city">
                          </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                          <label id="homepageformlabel">Class</label>
                          <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>Economy</option>
                            <option>Business</option>
                            <option>First</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 pt-3">
                            <button class="btn float-right" id="homepageformbutton" type="submit">Search flights</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
<script>
  // Amadeus origin airport search
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#inputOrigin").autocomplete({
          source: "{% url 'origin_airport_search' %}",
          minLength: 1,
          delay: 200,
      });
  });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

**Layout Template:**

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- jQuery & jQuery UI -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Main CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'flightfinder/styles.css' %}">

    <!-- Main JS -->
    <script src="{% static 'flightfinder/main.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>{% block title %}Flight Finder{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'flightfinder:index' %}">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/TRBkPBZ/Flight-Finder-removebg-preview.png" width="166" height="42" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="{% url 'flightfinder:index' %}">Flights <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Hotels</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Car Hire</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**Main - urls.py:**

```
"""finalproject URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('flightfinder.urls', namespace='Flightfinder')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**App - urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'flightfinder'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('origin_airport_search/', views.origin_airport_search, name='origin_airport_search')
]
```

**views.py:**

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from amadeus import Client, ResponseError, Location

from .models import Airport, Flight, Passenger

amadeus = Client(client_id='removed', 
                 client_secret='removed', 
                 log_level='debug') 

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'flightfinder/index.html')

def origin_airport_search(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        try:
            data = amadeus.reference_data.locations.get(keyword=request.GET.get('term', None), subType=Location.ANY).data
        except ResponseError as error:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, error)
    return HttpResponse(get_city_airport_list(data), 'application/json')

def get_city_airport_list(data):
    result = []
    for i, val in enumerate(data):
        result.append(data[i]['iataCode']+', '+data[i]['name'])
    result = list(dict.fromkeys(result))
    return json.dumps(result)
```

I have had a look through some similar stack queries, but none of them have helped thus far. Would be grateful if somebody had any ideas to try here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set a namespace "Flightfinders" in your include. This means you have to use this namespace to call your URL:

```
      source: "{% url 'Flightfinder:origin_airport_search' %}",
```

Comment: Thank you Antoine - this is working perfectly now! :)